# Is a sequence of normally distributed random variables bounded in probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $ \{Z_n\} $ be be a collection of independent random variables, say standard normal. In my script, we have the definition of "bounded in probability" given by:
$\{Z_n\}$ is bounded in probability if
$$\lim\limits_{M \rightarrow \infty} \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup{\mathbb{P}(\mid\mid Zn\mid\mid >M) } = 0$$

So since $\{Z_n\}$ is a sum of independent standard normal variables we know that it is also normal with mean 0 and variance n. So if we let n approach infinity the variance of this random sequence approaches infinity. Therefore, $\{Z_n\}$ is **not** bounded in probability. Does this reasoning make any sense?

Comment: So is $Z_n$ a collection of independent random variables or a sum of independent random variables?

Comment: It should be a collection of independent random variables, so my reasoning doesn't make sense

Comment: Hint: Apply Markov's inequality to get $\mathbb P(|Z_n| > M) \le \frac{1}{M} \mathbb E|Z_n|$.

Comment: Every (real-valued) random variable $X$ satisfies $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} P[|X|>M]=0$.  So every sequence of identically distributed random variables satisfies your definition (regardless of independence).

Comment: As Michael said, it is indeed even easier. For all I remember, if you have a family $\{Z_n\}_n$ such that $Z_n \sim \mathcal N(a_n, \sigma_n^2)$ (not necessarily independent and identically distributed), then $\{Z_n\}_n$ is "bounded in probability" (or equivalently (at least for countable family) "tight" as I would name it) if and only if, both families $\{a_n\}_n, \{\sigma_n^2\}_n$ are bounded.

Comment: Thanks alot! I guess I was confused because it's a sequence of RVs. But according to Dominik's answer, I did understand correctly that if $\{Z_n\}$ is a sum of independent normal variables it is not bounded (as the variance is not bounded).